# breaking down typedef structs in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, typedef

So I'm currently learning obj-c and came across this code in a header file that's provided by apple in CGGeometry.h header file.

```
struct
CGPoint {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CG_BOXABLE CGPoint CGPoint;
```

I don't understand the last portion of the code. This part:

```
typedef struct CG_BOXABLE CGPoint CGPoint;
```

So from my C days I remember defining a struct using typedef saves you from having to call it like so:

```
struct CGPoint{
}
```

And instead call it like this:

```
CGPoint{
}
```

But, what is the CG_BOXABLE and CGPoint? Is it like an inheritance thing or something? I'm referring to the first CGPoint.

Comment: The second `CGPoint` is exactly what you remember from your old C days. It's typedeffing `struct CGPoint` as `CGPoint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a newly added feature, adding the ability to box the struct without having to add your own `objc_boxable` attributes.

See the radar that seemingly started this feature request: http://openradar.appspot.com/32486932

Comment: Yup! I couldn't do it for 8 minutes and then totally forgot. Have a great day!